# Using Neo4j Cypher to find which nodes are not related to each other

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In Neo4j, I create a small graph with 4 nodes, some of which are linked to some others:

```
CREATE
(a:Room {name:"A"})
-[:DOOR]->
(b:Room {name:"B"})
-[:DOOR]->
(c:Room {name:"C"})
-[:DOOR]->
(d:Room {name:"D"}),
a-[:DOOR]->c,
a-[:DOOR]->d,
b-[:DOOR]->a
RETURN a,b,c,d
```

[image]

I want to find which rooms *do not* have a door between them. I'm hoping for an output something like this:

```
{"B": ["D"], "C": ["A", "B"], "D": ["A", "B", "C"]}
```

I can do this for one given starting point...

```
MATCH (b), (r)
WHERE b.name = "B"
AND NOT (b)-[:DOOR]->(r)
AND b <> r
RETURN r
// Returns Room D
```

Here's my cargo-cult pseudo code for iterating through each possible pair of nodes:

```
MATCH rooms = (r)
SET output = {}
FOREACH (
room IN nodes(rooms),
exit IN nodes(rooms),
missing = [],
output[room.name] = missing
|
IF room <> exit AND NOT room-[:DOOR]->(exit)
THEN missing = missing + exit
)
RETURN output
```

Please help me to understand how to formulate this correctly in Cypher.

Comment: I missed your edit before I answered, is the question how to do it for all pairs of nodes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `WHERE` clause takes relationship patterns and you can use the `NOT` function to filter on the absence of a relationship.

```
MATCH (a:Room), (b:Room)
WHERE NOT a-[:DOOR]-b AND a <> b
RETURN a, b
```

Here's the section in the [docs](http://neo4j.com/docs/milestone/query-where.html#where-filter-on-patterns-using-not).

Comment: I've added a line `AND a <> b`

Comment: Right, unless this is Alice in Wonderland or House of Leaves, rooms probably don't have doors to themselves :)